# TDD - unit tests which drive development but not tautological

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I have started to do some TDD and am enjoying the process but have come up against a problem.

I'm tending to write tests which are kind of 'wishful thinking' tests. By this I mean writing tests which assert that the unit has called methods which don't currently exist and then done something with the results - this requires a fair bit of mocking/stubbing. This has led me to write some nice code (I think) which has nice clean interfaces between different blocks of logic.

However, I've just had a look through some tests for a module I wrote and a lot of them seem like they are pretty pointless. They are basically asserting that what is written in the code, is written in the code. They will break as soon as I do any refactoring.

A toy problem I have been experimenting with: say I need to write a javascript `source` function for use in the [jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

The function needs to:

- check if data has already been pulled from the server (and if not do
  it)
- use that data to create an array of possible suggestions
- filter the array based on what the user has typed so far (for a bit of added complexity, in my experiments I have been assuming I want to actually create two arrays here - one which contains all the terms which start with the users input and one which contains all the terms which just contain the users input minus the ones in the first array)
- combine the arrays and pass them back to callback function

I see myself as having two options. I have been down both routes to compare.

I could start by writing tests that only test the business logic of my function (perhaps only mocking out a call to an ajax function that gets stuff from the server). Testing only that the function returns what it should do. This way I ended up with tests that won't break if I decide to refactor. But I also ended up with kind of messy code that I will probably want to refactor.

Or I could go down the 'wishful thinking' route - write tests that assert calls to (currently) imaginary methods and spread out the logic into smaller chunks. This drives development as the tests require that I write code to call those methods and then that I write more tests for the methods themselves etc.. I ended up with nicer code this time but I also seemed to end up with a bunch of tautological tests.

Am I missing something? Is there a happy middle ground to be had? Could any experienced TDDers give examples of what tests they would start with?

Comment: "tests which assert that the unit has called methods" this is the wrong approach: which methods the unit calls are almost always implementation details; your tests should not care *which* methods the unit calls, provided its externally visible behaviour is correct.

Comment: I think that is one interpretation. And certainly leads to tests that don't break when you refactor (or break less often). But then how do tests that don't care about implementation details *drive* development?

Answer (score 0):

TDD stands for **Test Driven** Design, meaning that your tests drive the code.

As you already said, when are doing 'wishful thinking' you end up with clean code, which is easy to read and maintain. Of course in this scenario you have more tests that look 'tautological' and you need more time to write them, but each of them describes your attention of the desired behavior. All the extra time that you've spent on additional tests, will be paid off later when you system starts growing, but your code will still remain clean and maintainable.

Comment: Although it's important to be careful not to write brittle tests that depend on implementation rather than results. It's not important that an array was created and sorted using algorithm X. The only important thing in the unit test should be that some given input results in the desired output

Comment: I disagree with the last statement. If you are doing TDD, your tests should describe the intention, not only the result. Very often you need to check that a certain interface/class is called with expected parameters, or method can simply return `void`.

Comment: Maybe "output" was a bad choice of words. I think there are 2 main types of outcomes to assert against: 1) correct value was returned 2) the correct call to some external resource (interface) or some global state was made. Might be more, but these should cover just about every case.

Comment: I'm not too worried about extra time writing tests as I know it will pay off in long run. But wondering if there is some techniques/methods I can use to try and avoid tests that are nearly useless (except for their initial effect on the design)

Comment: I'm writing tests in the same way: assert imaginary calls to classes/methods to have clear design, then I write integration tests with real data to assert than my method does what I expect. If I decide to refactor or modify method's implementation, I modify the code and tests accordingly. If you are not worried about time writing test, why do you want to avoid them?

Comment: Check this link as well http://stackoverflow.com/a/257460/4172979 it does give a good explanation.